# Swift Codable protocol with recursive enums

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift4, codable

Let's say that I have a model like the following, which allows me to build a tree of Foo objects.

```
struct Foo {

    var kind : Kind

    enum Kind {
        case node([Foo])
        case leaf
    }
}
```

How can I make this Codable, specifically for the `case node([Foo])`?

Comment: Nice question... but I don't think the Swift compiler will be able to synthesize the `Codoable` implementation for you -- looks like you gonna need to [write the coding yourself](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: Start with end in mind: what do you want the JSON to look like? Or do you already have the JSON and want to read it into Swift?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I don't care about the JSON structure really, just that I can serialize/deserialize a tree. ;) I know how to implement the init/encode methods to handle enums with associated types but not where the associated type is an array of a custom struct.

Comment: @PauloMattos Right but how does one implement decoding and encoding of the array? Do I have to recursively iterate through it or will it just work magically as long as Foo is Codable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the final struct, based on the answer from @PauloMattos:

Base Foo struct:

```
struct Foo {

    var name: String
    var kind: Kind

    enum Kind {
        case node([Foo])
        case leaf
    }

    init(name: String, kind: Kind) {
        self.name = name
        self.kind = kind
    }
}
```

Codable Protocol extension:

```
extension Foo : Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case nodes
    }

    enum CodableError: Error {
        case decoding(String)
        case encoding(String)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        switch kind {
        case .node(let nodes):
            var array = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .nodes)
            try array.encode(contentsOf: nodes)
            break
        case .leaf:
            break
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        // Assumes name exists for all objects
        if let name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name) {
            self.name = name
            self.kind = .leaf
            if let array = try? container.decode([Foo].self, forKey: .nodes) {
                self.kind = .node(array)
            }
            return
        }
        throw CodableError.decoding("Decoding Error")
    }
}
```

CustomStringConvertable Protocol extension (to output string from the tree):

```
extension Foo : CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        return stringDescription(self)
    }

    private func stringDescription(_ foo: Foo) -> String {
        var string = ""
        switch foo.kind {
        case .leaf:
            return foo.name
        case .node(let nodes):
            string += "\(foo.name): ("
            for i in nodes.indices {
                string += stringDescription(nodes[i])
                // Comma seperate all but the last
                if i < nodes.count - 1 { string += ", " }
            }
            string += ")"
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

And example testing code:

```
let a = Foo(name: "A", kind: .leaf)
let b = Foo(name: "B", kind: .leaf)
let c = Foo(name: "C", kind: .leaf)
let d = Foo(name: "D", kind: .node([b, c]))
let root = Foo(name: "ROOT", kind: .node([a, d]))

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(root)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print("Foo to JSON:")
print(json)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let foo = try decoder.decode(Foo.self, from: jsonData)
    print("JSON to Foo:")
    print(foo)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

```
Foo to JSON:
{
  "name" : "ROOT",
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "name" : "A"
    },
    {
      "name" : "D",
      "nodes" : [
        {
          "name" : "B"
        },
        {
          "name" : "C"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
JSON to Foo:
ROOT: (A, D: (B, C))
```

Comment: Something else, for completeness: A cleaner implementation for this could also be to implement Codable on the Kind enum itself. This makes it more reusable and the Foo struct can simply support Codable automatically, since Foundation vars already conform.

Answer (score 5):

One possible *encoding* for the `Foo` recursive data type could be:

```
struct Foo: Encodable {
    var name: String // added a per-node payload as well.
    var kind: Kind

    enum Kind {
        case node([Foo])
        case leaf
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case nodes
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var dict = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try dict.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        switch kind {
        case .node(let nodes):
            var array = dict.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .nodes)
            try array.encode(contentsOf: nodes)
        case .leaf:
            break // Nothing to encode. 
        }
    }
}
```

A simple test using the JSON encoder:

```
let a = Foo(name: "A", kind: .leaf)
let b = Foo(name: "C", kind: .leaf)
let c = Foo(name: "B", kind: .leaf)
let root = Foo(name: "ROOT", kind: .node([a, b, c]))

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(root)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)
```

would then output the following JSON:

```
{
  "name" : "ROOT",
  "nodes" : [
    {
      "name" : "A"
    },
    {
      "name" : "C"
    },
    {
      "name" : "B"
    }
  ]
}
```

Conforming to `Decodable` should follow a similar logic ;)

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I'll test this out tomorrow but it looks like your bit of `var array = dict.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .nodes)
            try array.encode(contentsOf: nodes)` code is what I was missing.

Comment: Note you can simplify that entire `switch` statement down to `if case .node(let nodes) = kind { try container.encode(nodes, forKey: .nodes) }` :)

Comment: @PauloMattos: Hmm. The decode doesn't appear as straightforward as expected ;) I am able to pull out the root node but nothing further. Maybe there's an issue in the encode or do I need to rebuild the tree by walking the nodes array? Mind posting a solution for the init?

Comment: @PauloMattos: Nevermind. ;) This was actually due to a bug in my recursive string output. Will post complete code below for reference shortly.

Comment: @PauloMattos: I'm going to mark my answer with the check so that others are more likely to see the more complete answer. Let me know if that somehow takes away any points you get for your help.

Comment: @joshd Hey man, no problem... the *complete* answer should be *accepted* one, no questions there — please go ahead ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos: Great!

Comment: @Hamish Nice idiom, but I somewhat enjoy the readability/maintainability that an exhaustive `swift` provides. Anyway, thanks for the feedback man ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos No worries – you can still simplify the `.node` case down to `try container.encode(nodes, forKey: .nodes)` though :)

Answer (score -1):

[Here is a great post](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375) of `Decoadable` protocol and its usage.

I think at the bottom of the post in the **Enum** section you can find what you need, but if you don't want to read the article [here is the gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zntfdr/8526dcfb087d1a0820e339d8f97be35c/raw/756f14c74227678251b22acf8e89e7b8e207f159/enumArray.swift) which can be helpful.