# Swift Codable protocol with recursive enums to encode JSON

Tags: json, swift, recursion, enums, codable

I'm new to Swift Codable and I trying to encode a "complex" JSON structure from myself. It is a little difficult, because it needs to be recursive.

I found an solution on stack overflow for revusive enums, but it I fail to implement it for my JSON in Swift. ([Swift Codable protocol with recursive enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139768/swift-codable-protocol-with-recursive-enums)) I got a solution for python but in Swift is much more complicated.

The JSON file would be something like this:

```
[
 {
 "id": 0,
 "name": "Simple Rule A",
     "operations": {
              "attribute": "C",
              "value": false
              }
 },
 {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Simple Rule A",
 "operations": {
     "ruleOperator": "AND",
     "ruleOperand":[
              {
              "attribute": "A",
              "value": false
              },
              {
              "attribute": "C",
              "value": false
              }
              ]
     }
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Simple Rule B",
 "operations": {
 "ruleOperator": "AND",
 "ruleOperand":[
          {"ruleOperator": "OR",
          "ruleOperand":[
                   {
                   "attribute": "A",
                   "value": false
                   },
                   {
                   "attribute": "C",
                   "value": false
                   }
                   ]
          },
          {
          "attribute": "C",
          "value": false
          }
          ]
 }
 }

 ]
```

It is a array with Rules and every rule has an id and name and there operations. The operations can be a "node" with an Operator and Operands or "leafs" as an Operand with attribute and value.

Thats what I got:

```
import Foundation

struct Rule: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let operations: Operations
}

struct Operations {

    //var ruleOperator: String

    var ruleOperator: String?
    var kind: Kind?

    enum Kind {
        case node([Operations])
        case leaf(Operand)
    }

    init(name: String, ruleOp: String, kind: Kind) {
        self.ruleOperator = ruleOp
        self.kind = kind
    }
}

extension Operations: Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case ruleOperator
        case nodes
        case test
    }

    enum CodableError: Error {
        case decoding(String)
        case encoding(String)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let someRuleOperator = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .ruleOperator) {
            self.ruleOperator = someRuleOperator
        }

        if let someOperand = try container.decodeIfPresent(Operand.self, forKey: .nodes) {
            self.kind = .leaf(someOperand)
        }

        if let array = try? container.decode([Operations].self, forKey: .nodes) {
            self.kind = .node(array)
        }
        return
    }
}

struct Operand: Decodable {
    let attribute: String
    let value: Bool
}

enum Operator {
    case IS
    case AND
    case OR
    case XOR
}
```

The Problem is the "init(from decoder: Decoder)" part. Also the "ruleOperator: String?" as an Optional is crap.

Maybe some one can help me :) and give me a hint in the right direction.

(Also nice would be help how I can use the Operator enum instead of the string for e.g. "IS" or "AND".)

### Solution

Rework the JSON structure and use this solution [Swift Codable protocol with recursive enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139768/swift-codable-protocol-with-recursive-enums)

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Simple Rule A",
 "operations": [
                   {
                   "attribute": "AND",
                   "value": null,
                   "operations": [
                                {
                                "attribute": "A",
                                "value": true,
                                "operations": []
                                },
                                {
                                "attribute": "B",
                                "value": true,
                                "operations": []
                                }
                                ]
                   }
               ]
 }
```

Comment: So it seems the issue is that `Rule.operations` isn't decoded in some cases? And you also want to change the type of `Operations.ruleOperator` to `Operator` instead of `String?`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor My main issue is, that I can not handle the `struct Operand` in the JSON. I don't know how to implement it in the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` func.

Comment: I go a solution: Just reworked the JSON structure to a simpler solution. Edited my question if somebody got the same question.