# JSON decode to and encode from recursive enum in Swift

Tags: json, swift, recursion, enums, codable

I have a JSON file that can look like this:

```
{
    "items" : [
        { "name": "a name", "version": "a version" },
        { "version": "a 2nd version" },
        {
            "any_of": [
                { "name": "some name" },
                { "name": "some other name", "version": "some other version" },
                [
                    { "name": "another name" },
                    { "version": "another version" },
                    {
                        "any_of": [
                            [
                                { "version": "some version" },
                                { "version": "some version" }
                            ],
                            { "version": "yet another version" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "any_of" : [
                { "name": "a name" },
                { "name": "another name" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON file has a recursive structure. The `any_of` key indicates an `OR` relationship between all elements in its array, and the lack of `any_of` key indicates an `AND` relationship. I want to decode (and encode) the JSON file using Swift's `Codable` protocol, and currently I have a `Codable` struct that represents the `name` `version` JSON object:

```swift
struct NameVersion: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let version: String?

    func toString() -> String { "\(name ?? "")\(version ?? "")" }
}
```

and a `Codable` enum that represents the entire JSON structure:

```swift
enum Items: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //  decode from JSON here
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //  encode to JSON here
    }

    case item(NameVersion)

    //  A set of `Items` instances with an "OR" relationship.
    //  This represents a JSON array with an "any_of" key.
    case anyOfItems(Set<Items>)

    //  A set of `Items` instances with an "AND" relationship
    //  This represents a JSON array without an "any_of" key.
    case allOfItems(Set<Items>)

    //  This function might help illustrate the structure and my goal.
    func toString() -> String {
        switch self {
        case let .item(item):
            return item.toString()
        case let .anyOfItems(items):
            return "(\(items.map { $0.toString() }.joined(separator: " ∨ ")))"
        case let .allOfItems(items):
            return "(\(items.map { $0.toString() }.joined(separator: " ∧ ")))"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble implementing the `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` functions for the `Items` enum. I checked the Stack Overflow question [Swift Codable protocol with recursive enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139768/swift-codable-protocol-with-recursive-enums), but my situation differs from it that my enum isn't nested in a struct, and my `item`'s associated value of `NameVersion` type does not come directly from a key-value pair.

Comment: this is not a proper json... try to complete your json

Comment: @MohamadRezaKoohakn I checked my json against the [json standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), and don't see how's it's not a proper json. Could you point out where the errors in my json are? Thanks.

Comment: Likely improper JSON means no open/close {} since this is an object. Does this tool help you get going at all? https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: A JSON begins and ends either with {...} or [...]

Comment: @Brian thanks for the edit. I tried app.quicktype.io, and although it understands the recursion from a JSON schema, it's not able to produce concise code that conforms to the `Codable` protocol. I think I found a solution using `UnkeyedDecodingContainer`, and I'm testing it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying practically everything, I found that the best approach to decode the JSON is through the [`UnkeyedDecodingContainer` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unkeyeddecodingcontainer).

According to the documentation, an unkeyed container "is used to hold the encoded properties of a decodable type sequentially, without keys." This describes a perfect match for the given JSON structure.

Since `Codable` is just an alias for `Decodable` and `Encodable`, let's make `Items` conform to `Decodable` first before `Encodable`.

---

### `Decodable` Conformance

Given this `Codable` structure that holds bottom-level JSON objects:

```
struct NameVersion: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let version: String?
}
```

To decode the JSON:

```swift
indirect enum Items: Codable {

    /**
    Initialises an `Items` instance by decoding from the given `decoder`.

    - Parameter decoder: The decoder to read data from.
    */
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //  
        //  This initialiser is designed recursively decode nested JSON arrays into 
        //  recursive Swift enums, so we need an instance of a collection type to 
        //  hold all the intermediate results.
        //  
        //  Because the unkeyed values in JSON are in a sequence, and because 2 of 
        //  Item's cases have associated values of Set<Items> type, we need a 
        //  Set<Items> variable to hold all the values while the JSON values are 
        //  decoded one by one.
        var itemsSet: Set<Items> = []

        //  Create an unkeyed container holding the current level of JSON values.
        var unkeyedValues = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        //  "Loop" through values in the unkeyed container.
        //  The unkeyed container does not conform to the `Sequence` protocol, 
        //  but its `currentIndex` property grows by 1 every time when a value 
        //  is decoded successfully.
        while unkeyedValues.count! > unkeyedValues.currentIndex {
            let containerIndexBeforeLoop = unkeyedValues.currentIndex

            //  Case 1: the JSON value decodes to a NameVersion instance.
            if let nameVersion = try? unkeyedValues.decode(NameVersion.self) {
                itemsSet.insert(Items.item(nameVersion))
            } 

            //  Case 2: the JSON value is a { "any_of": [] } object.
            //  This requires a service structure to take care of it. 
            //  More detailed explanation on this later.
            else if let anyOfItems = try? unkeyedValues.decode(AnyOfItems.self) {
                itemsSet.insert(anyOfItems.items)
            } 

            //  Case 3: the JSON value is an array without a key.
            else if let items = try? unkeyedValues.decode(Items.self) {
                itemsSet.insert(items)
            }

            //  If the unkeyed container's current index didn't increase by 1 
            //  during this loop, then the the unkeyed value at the current index 
            //  was not decoded, and will not be in future loops. There is no way 
            //  to increment the index manually, so the unkeyed container will keep 
            //  trying for the same value. The only choice is to break out of the 
            //  loop in this situation.
            if unkeyedValues.currentIndex <= containerIndexBeforeLoop { break }
        }

        if itemsSet.count == 1 {
            //  If there is only 1 Item in the set, we can just assign it to self.
            self = ItemsSet.popFirst()!
        } else {
            //  Since all "any_of" JSON arrays are taken care of by the service 
            //  structure, all Items instances in the set are decoded from an 
            //  unkeyed JSON array.
            self = .allOfItems(itemsSet)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //  TODO: encode to JSON here
    }

    case item(NameVersion)

    //  A set of `Items` instances with an "OR" relationship.
    //  This represents a JSON array with an "any_of" key.
    case anyOfItems(Set<Items>)

    //  A set of `Item` instances with an "AND" relationship
    //  This represents a JSON array without an "any_of" key.
    case allOfItems(Set<Items>)
}
```

Although there exists a `.nestedContainer()` method for getting a nested keyed container from within the unkeyed container, that holds the data of an `{ "any_of": [] }` JSON object, the nested container is unable to call the `decode(forKey:, from:)` method to decode JSON.

Instead, I followed [this solution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types) for decoding nested data, and created the following service struct for decoding `{ "any_of": [] }` JSON objects.

```
struct AnyOfItems: Codable {

    /**
    Initialises an `Items` instance by decoding from the given `decoder`.

    - Parameter decoder: The decoder to read data from.
    */
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var itemsSet: Set<Items> = []

        var unkeyedValues = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        while unkeyedValues.count! > unkeyedValues.currentIndex {
            let containerIndexBeforeLoop = unkeyedValues.currentIndex

            if let nameVersion = try? unkeyedValues.decode(NameVersion.self) {
                itemsSet.insert(Items.item(nameVersion))
            } else if let anyOfItems = try? unkeyedValues.decode(AnyOfItems.self) {
                itemsSet.insert(anyOfItems.items)
            } else if let items = try? unkeyedValues.decode(Items.self) {
                itemsSet.insert(items)
            }

            if unkeyedValues.currentIndex <= containerIndexBeforeLoop { break }
        }

        if itemsSet.count == 1 {
            items = itemsSet.popFirst()!
        } else {
            //  The decoding part for AnyOfItems is largely the same as that for 
            //  Items, but they differ in that for AnyOfItems, the set of Items 
            //  are given to the .anyOfItems case.
            itsms = Items.anyOfItems(itemsSet)
        }
    }

    let items: Items
}
```

The majority of the repeated code can be extracted to its own function:

```
indirect enum Items: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //  Still has to be a variable, because .popFirst() is a mutating method.
        var itemsSet: Set<Items> = try decodeItems(from: decoder)
        if itemsSet.count == 1 { self = ItemsSet.popFirst()! } 
        else { self = .allOfItems(itemsSet) }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //  TODO: encode to JSON here
    }

    case item(NameVersion)
    case anyOfItems(Set<Items>)
    case allOfItems(Set<Items>)
}

struct AnyOfItems: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var itemsSet: Set<Items> = try decodeItems(from: decoder)
        if itemsSet.count == 1 { items = itemsSet.popFirst()! } 
        else { items = Items.anyOfItems(itemsSet) }
    }

    let items: Items
}

func decodeItems(from decoder: Decoder) throws -> Set<Items> {
    var itemsSet: Set<Items> = []
    var unkeyedValues = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

    while unkeyedValues.count! > unkeyedValues.currentIndex {
        let containerIndexBeforeLoop = unkeyedValues.currentIndex

        if let nameVersion = try? unkeyedValues.decode(NameVersion.self) {
            itemsSet.insert(Items.item(nameVersion))
        } else if let anyOfItems = try? unkeyedValues.decode(AnyOfItems.self) {
            itemsSet.insert(anyOfItems.items)
        } else if let items = try? unkeyedValues.decode(Items.self) {
            itemsSet.insert(items)
        }

        if unkeyedValues.currentIndex <= containerIndexBeforeLoop { break }
    }

    return itemsSet
}
```

---

### `Encodable` Conformance

Encoding is much simpler.

```
indirect enum Items: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //  JSON decoded here
    }

    /**
    Encodes an `Items` instance`.

    - Parameter encoder: The encoder to encode data to.
    */
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        switch self {
        case .item(let item):
            try container.encode(item)
        case .allOfItems(let items):
            try container.encode(contentsOf: items)
        case .anyOfItems(let items):
            try container.encode(AnyOfItems(Items.anyOfItems(items)))
        }
    }

    case item(NameVersion)
    case anyOfItems(Set<Items>)
    case allOfItems(Set<Items>)
}

struct AnyOfItems: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //  JSON decoded here
    }

    /**
    Encodes an `Items` instance`.

    - Parameter encoder: The encoder to encode data to.
    */
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(items, forKey: .items)
    }

    /**
    A memberwise initialiser.
    */
    init(_ items: Items) {
        self.items = items
    }

    let items: Items

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items = "any_of"
    }
}
```

---

### `Codable` Conformance

Finally, with everything put together:

```
indirect enum Items: Codable {

    /**
    Initialises an `Items` instance by decoding from the given `decoder`.

    - Parameter decoder: The decoder to read data from.
    */
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var itemsSet: Set<Items> = try decodeItems(from: decoder)

        if itemsSet.count == 1 { 
            self = ItemsSet.popFirst()! 
        } else { 
            self = .allOfItems(itemsSet) 
        }
    }

    /**
    Encodes an `Items` instance`.

    - Parameter encoder: The encoder to encode data to.
    */
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        switch self {
        case .item(let item):
            try container.encode(item)
        case .allOfItems(let items):
            try container.encode(contentsOf: items)
        case .anyOfItems(let items):
            try container.encode(AnyOfItems(Items.anyOfItems(items)))
        }
    }

    case item(NameVersion)
    case anyOfItems(Set<Items>)
    case allOfItems(Set<Items>)
}

struct AnyOfItems: Codable {

    /**
    Initialises an `Items` instance by decoding from the given `decoder`.

    - Parameter decoder: The decoder to read data from.
    */
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var itemsSet: Set<Items> = try decodeItems(from: decoder)

        if itemsSet.count == 1 { 
            items = itemsSet.popFirst()! 
        } else { 
            items = Items.anyOfItems(itemsSet) 
        }
    }

    /**
    Encodes an `Items` instance`.

    - Parameter encoder: The encoder to encode data to.
    */
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(items, forKey: .items)
    }

    /**
    A memberwise initialiser.
    */
    init(_ items: Items) {
        self.items = items
    }

    let items: Items

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items = "any_of"
    }
}

func decodeItems(from decoder: Decoder) throws -> Set<Items> {
    var itemsSet: Set<Items> = []
    var unkeyedValues = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

    while unkeyedValues.count! > unkeyedValues.currentIndex {
        let containerIndexBeforeLoop = unkeyedValues.currentIndex

        if let nameVersion = try? unkeyedValues.decode(NameVersion.self) {
            itemsSet.insert(Items.item(nameVersion))
        } else if let anyOfItems = try? unkeyedValues.decode(AnyOfItems.self) {
            itemsSet.insert(anyOfItems.items)
        } else if let items = try? unkeyedValues.decode(Items.self) {
            itemsSet.insert(items)
        }

        if unkeyedValues.currentIndex <= containerIndexBeforeLoop { break }
    }

    return itemsSet
}
```